# How to access named slots inside svelte component?

Tags: javascript, slots, svelte

I'm trying out Svelte (great!) but I'm running into a problem that I don't know how to solve. I have a component with a couple of named slots. Based on whether these slots are filled, I need to render some additional HTML. So my idea was to put these blocks inside an `{{#if slots}}` block, but I don't know how to refer to the named slots. Trying `this.options.slots` in `oncreate`, I can see the collection of slots, but I don't know how to get to them in the HTML part of my component. Anyone able to help me out?
[See this REPL](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.49.1&gist=adbc5ae2d68e8838d1a85279b888fbd1)

Comment: Uhmmm, this.set() should do the trick. Silly me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elco already figured out the answer and mentioned it in a comment, but for anyone else who comes across this — it's a little hacky, but you can do `this.set(...)` in the `oncreate` hook:

```
oncreate () {
  this.set({
    hasEmail: !!this.options.slots.email
  });
}
```

[Demo here](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.49.1&gist=886c1a2c0b6cec5e1fe192ffa190067f).

Comment: Thanks Rich (and a big thank you for you terrific work on svelte and sapper), I have another issue with these named slots: I'd like to place custom components like this `<MTitle slot="title">Title here</MTitle>` but that doesn't work. I have to do `<span slot="title"><MTitle>Title here</MTitle></span>` which is not very elegant of course. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Not currently. Slotted components is something we could conceivably support in future, but unfortunately only slotted elements are supported for now.

Comment: By all means please do!